# Expected indented block Error in Python for a login system

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please, I need help with this login system that I am currently working on, but I keep on getting the indented block error at def password(). I'm new to python but have worked with Java for a few years.
    I have tried to indent the def password(), but it just keeps on popping up.

```
def username():
    userinputname = input('Please enter the username')
    if userinputname == user:
        password()
    elif userinputname != user:
        print('Wrong username, please try again')
        username()
    else:
        # problems()3


def password():
    userinputpass = input('Please enter the password')
    if  userinputpass == passs:   
        main()
    elif userinputpass != passs
        for x <=5:  
            print('Wrong password, please try again')
            x++
        exit
    else:
        # problems()


def register():
    registeragain = False
    user = input('Please register your username')
    passs = input('Please register your password')
    register = input('Do you want to register another account? Y/N')
        if register == 'Y':
            registeragain = True
        elif register == 'N':
            username()
        else:
            print("Error")
            # problems()

register()
```

I ran the problem and the error showed expected an indented block (, line 12)

Comment: A comment isn't a valid block statement body.

Comment: Besides indentation there is a lot more syntax error in your code

Comment: oh, can you please help me with that

Comment: It's my first day into Python

Comment: If it is your first day into Python, you should not be writing a program that long.

Comment: As I said, I have had a few years of experience with Java, and I pick things up fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   else:
        # problems()3


def password():
```

The `expected indented block` error happens because you're supposed to have an indented block of code following an `else:`.  Instead, you go directly from there to an unindent (starting a new function definition).

If you put a `pass` statement under your `else` that will satisfy the requirement for there to be a block under it.  Alternatively you could just remove the `else` since it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared an else statement at the end of each function without including anything to execute within the statement. Else statements expect an indented block of code, hence the problem.

If your intention is to do nothing in an 'else' block, use a 'pass' statement.

```
else:
    pass
    # problems()
```

Instead of below, which is causing problems.

```
 else:
     # problems()
```